# Use a for loop to add new sheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a `For...Next` loop to create a set number of `Worksheet`s in a `Workbook`. The the number of worksheets is set by the user from a dashboard, at an earlier point.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? This is my code, so far:

```
For i = 1 To siteCount
    'I know the below won't work, and I also tried site_ & i, but no luck
    Set site_i = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
    site_i.Name = "Sheet Name"
Next i
```

Comment: Did you declare variable `site_i`?

Comment: I publicly declared the max number of sheets that could be used...in `site_1`, `site_2`, ......`site_n`.

Comment: I think you should better try to use an array instead of dynamic variable names (which does not work in VBA)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the way to go. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some small adjustments, your code will basically work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheets()

    Dim siteCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim site_i As Worksheet

    siteCount = 4

    For i = 1 To siteCount
        Set site_i = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
        site_i.Name = "Sheet_Name_" & CStr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The above will work perfect and all but the declaration and assigning of `site_i` is pointless (I realize you're just working from the OP's code but I'd suggest something like `Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet_Name_" & CStr(i)` (and then deleting the second line of the iteration

Comment: @Jeremy thanks. I noticed that myself, but his logic is better. I will mark it as accepted.