# Error creating create sheets with for loop in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

As part of bigger Macro at some point I have to create a certain numbers of sheets in certain position.

To do that and, as I am a begginer with macros (and programming in general) I have done a test with a simple scenario.

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424477/use-a-for-loop-to-add-new-sheets-in-workbook)

But, adapting that code to my case I'm only able to create the first sheet and getting an error in the following.

The code right now is this:

```
Sub AddSheets()

Dim siteCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

siteCount = 2


For i = 1 To siteCount
    Name = Cells(i, 26)
    Set site_i = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets("DLC_" & CStr(Name)))
    site_i.Name = "DLC" & CStr(Name)

Next i
End Sub
```

What I'm not seeing?

Comment: What is the error? On which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your idea is to add worksheets to a workbook, based on the values of cells Z1 and Z2, this is a possible solution. First, make sure you actually have some values in Z1 and Z2, in the first worksheet of your workbook.

[image]

Z1 and Z2 are used, because they are referred in the original question here:
    `Name = Cells(i, 26)`. The `Cells()` takes first the row and then the column. Then run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheets()

    Dim siteCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim name  As String
    siteCount = 2

    Dim newWks As Worksheet

    For i = 1 To siteCount
        With Worksheets(1)
            name = .Cells(i, 26)
            If .Cells(i, 26) <> "" Then
                Set newWks = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                newWks.Name = .Cells(i, 26)
            Else
                MsgBox Cells(i, 26).Address & "is empty"
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

The worksheets are added with:
`Set newWks = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))`

Their name is changed with 
`newWks.Name = .Cells(i, 26)`

[How to Add a Named Sheet at the end of all excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets)

If you run the code twice, you would get an error, because the worksheets with the corresponding names would exist already in the workbook.

Comment: ... and @Carlos shouldn't use VBA-internal terms like "name" as variable name.